# Exception encountered during the startup of Cassandra on windows 10

Tags: cassandra, datastax-startup

I have installed Cassandra on windows10 system distributed by Datastax. It was working fine as excepted, however after my system restart the service fails to start with the following error

> Exception encountered during startup 
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ebc5f4f0-7a0e-11e8-8cc9-7929f888de3b is already bound in reverseMap to (system_distributed,ananth)

Please kindly help us in this.

Comment: Are you using the DSE, or DataStax distribution of Cassandra?

Comment: We are using the DataStax distribution

Comment: You mean DSE or Cassandra distribution from DATASTAX?